# No me muestra la tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Pues eso, estoy intentado que me muestre una `tooltip` en un campo input y no me la muestra, no sé donde estoy teniendo el error.

```js
//Javascript (JQuery)
$(function test()
{
    var valor = $("#nombre").val();
 if( valor == null || valor.length == 0) {
   $("#nombre").tooltip({
   content: "texto de prueba"
   });
   return false;
 } else { return true;}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="nombre" onclick="test();">
```

Seguro que es una tontería pero no soy capaz de visualizarla.

Comment: ¿el tooltip lo hiciste tú o usas alguna librería?¿en la consola no te aparece ningún error?

Comment: Como he puesto en los tags, utilizo JQuery UI, tengo todas las librerías bien importadas, el error que me tira la consola es: Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Comment: @Cifu, revisa que tu página tenga las referencias a JQuery-UI. si es así, por favor edita tu pregunta con las librerías que usas para el widget de tooltip de JQuery.

Comment: Las librerías funcionan correctamente, lo he comprobado ahora mismo haciendo un alert de jquery y un progressbar de jquery ui, pondría las librerías en la pregunta pero son locales y ya os doy la garantía de que funcionan perfectamente.

Comment: @Cifu creo que faltaba el atributo title, te respondi

Comment: para siguientes preguntas, agrega el HTML de donde llamas a las librerías :D buena respuesta @x-rw !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faltaba agregar las debidas librerias, y el atributo title en el input

```js
function test()
{
 var valor = $("#nombre").val();
 if( valor == null || valor.length == 0) {
 $("#nombre").tooltip({
  content: "texto de prueba"
 });
      return false;
      } else { return true;}
 };
```

```html
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Tooltip - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="nombre" title="faltaba title" onclick="test();">
```

Comment: Extraño, pero tenía agregadas y comprobadas ambas librerías:  <script src="../Portfolio/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Portfolio/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> además del css y no funciona en concreto eso, pero bueno, ahora funciona bien, gracias !!

Comment: Vale, el problema exactamente no eran las librerías en sí, si no la versión de éstas, que estaban un poco desactualizadas.

Answer (score 1):

1. Verifica que JQuery sea la primera libreria que llamas.
2. El código que ejecutas debe estar después de la llamada a JQuery.
3. En tu código `$(function test()` reemplazalo por `function test()` sin el signo de dólar al inicio.

Comment: 1. Verificadas y funcionan 2. El código está por debajo de la llamada a las librerías 3. De esa manera no me tira nada en consola pero me sigue sin mostrar la tooltip.